# Motion of molecules is random or uniform vibration with a frequency?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, vibrations, molecular-dynamics

Every substance has an entropy, entropy is defined as the randomness in a system. There's also a term called molecular vibration which tells the periodic vibration of molecules and gives them a frequency. I've always thought heat of a substance is a property which defines the amount of random movement of the molecules in a substance, if it is random I don't think we can define a frequency to the molecules' movement, but the vibrations defined have a frequency which means they trace the same path again and again, i.e., not random. So my question is do molecules have frequency? If they have, how is entropy defined? Is it different for different states of matter(difference maybe between fluids and solids, I'm not sure)?

Answer (score 1):

> I've always thought heat of a substance is a property which defines
> the amount of random movement of the molecules in a substance

That is not heat. It is a component of the internal molecular kinetic energy of the substance. Heat is not a thermodynamic property. Heat is energy transfer between substances due solely to temperature difference. The energy transfer can result in an increase or decrease in the internal energy of a substance.

> if it is random I don't think we can define a frequency to the
> molecules' movement, but the vibrations defined have a frequency which
> means they trace the same path again and again, i.e., not random.

Molecular vibrational, as well as molecular rotational kinetic energy is not random motion. Translational kinetic energy is random motion. The total molecular kinetic energy (total internal kinetic energy) is the sum of vibrational, rotational, and translational kinetic energies.

> So my question is do molecules have frequency?

Yes, it's there vibrational frequency. See the Wikipedia article on "Molecular vibration".

> If they have, how is entropy defined? Is it different for different
> states of matter(difference maybe between fluids and solids, I'm not
> sure)

Molecular vibration, rotation, and translation are three potential molecular degrees of freedom. The more degrees of freedom, the higher the entropy since increasing the number of degrees of freedom increases the entropy. Only a perfectly ordered, crystalline substance at absolute zero would exhibit no molecular motion and have zero entropy.

The entropy of a substance increases as it undergoes phase changes from a solid, to a  liquid, to gas.

> I've one more doubt, what do you mean by more degrees of freedom? Do
> you mean magnitude or fourth degree of motion?

I'm referring to the three types or categories of molecular degrees of freedom and their association with entropy. In that respect, a molecule can have potentially have three molecular types of degrees of freedom: translational, vibrational, and rotational, and a total number of 3N degrees of freedom, where N equals the number of atoms in the molecule. For example, in the case of a monatomic gas where $N=1$, rotational and vibrational modes do not apply, only translational. Thus the number of degrees of freedom is 3 for motion in 3 dimensions of space. I'm no expert on all the details, so I suggest you check out "Modes in Polyatomic Molecules" on the chem.librexts.org web site or other resource.

In any case, these three types of molecular degrees of freedom are ways in which molecules can store energy. The greater the molecular motion of a system, the greater the number of possible microstates and the higher the entropy.

> hi, just a clarification. I thought all the atoms of molecule have the
> same molecular vibration, does each atom have different molecular
> vibration?

It can be different, it depends on the molecule. For example, there are three possible vibration modes in a non linear triatomic molecule: 1.symmetrical stretching, 2. asymmetrical stretching, and 3. scissoring (bending). You can see an animation of these by looking up "Particle Model of Thermal Energy" on the phy.libretexts.org website.

> If there's only one atom in molecule why doesn't vibrational modes
> doesn't apply? I thought all atoms and molecules always vibrate unless
> it's 0K temperature

Molecular vibration motion is due to atoms bonded to each other within a molecule having certain freedom of movement relative to each other. Think of a diatomic (two atom) gas with a spring connecting the two atoms and the two atoms oscillating.  A monatomic molecule only has one atom so there can be no relative movement between atoms of a monatomic molecule.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I always thought entropy is random movement of molecules, but now I know it's not random, but combination of three degrees of freedom vibration, rotation and translation, so effectively we can calculate the frequency of the vibration of the molecule, i.e., if the body of matter is not moving(zero translation) then each molecule traces the same path again and again every t seconds and 1/t is the frequency of the molecular vibration. I've one more doubt, what do you mean by more degrees of freedom? Do you mean magnitude or fourth degree of motion?

Comment: @user41965 I've attempted to address your last doubt with an update to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user41965 It sounds like you are under the impression that there is a single oscillation frequency which characterizes the motion of all of the atoms and molecules in the system, which is not at all the case.

Comment: @J.Murray I don't believe I said (or intended to give) that impression.

Comment: @BobD No, I agree that you did not.  That's just how I interpreted OP's response to your question, which may not be an accurate interpretation on my part.

Comment: @BobD hi, just a clarification. I thought all the atoms of molecule have the same molecular vibration, does each atom have different molecular vibration? If there's only one atom in molecule why doesn't vibrational modes doesn't apply? I thought all atoms and molecules always vibrate unless it's 0K temperature

Comment: @user41965 One last time. See my latest update on your need for clarification. Hope it helps because I really can't spend any more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Molecules can vibrate with one or more frequencies , given the energy  and move around, some of the energy goes to oscillation, but you can  run around randomly  and move you head or arm with some fixed frequency